# How to erase part of shape in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers, mask, layer-style

I want to erase part of a rectangle but it gets erased in the way shown in the right hand image:

[image: Incorrect erasing of rectangle]

I want to be like this:

[image: Desired erasing of rectangle]

Comment: What have you tried that didn't work? Also: https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/masking-layers.html

Comment: I edit question.

Answer (score 6):

I'm guessing you're using a *stroke layer style* on your shape in Photoshop.

If you use a [Layer Mask](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/masking-layers.html) directly on the layer that has the shape with the effect, it will create the result you see on your top image. It won't delete the stroke but create a new "path" for it to follow instead, the stroke will simply wrap that shape and still be visible.

But if you put that layer into a "[layer group](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/selecting-grouping-linking-layers.html#group_and_link_layers)" and add that layer mask to that group instead, you'll get the result on your second image. It will erase/mask the stroke layer effect as well or any other layer style you used on the layers within that group. This can be useful for drop shadows too.

[image: layer mask on a group]

Answer (score 2):

Should really consider using Shape instead with Fill and Stroke. Then when you use a Layer Mask to erase part of it the Stroke won't be affected. It will give you a better workflow for most things while keeping things higher quality and less destructive.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If using layer style effects to get the border (stroke in layer effects) then you want to toggle the "Layer Mask Hides Effects" checkbox under "Blending Options".
[image]